# How to set a slider change listener to fire only when mouse drag is released in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, slider, mouseevent

I have a working code in JavaFX for sliders, but it fires everytime there is any change in the slider and I want it to only fire a change when the mouse drag event is released.

Below is the code:

```
sliderMarkerSize.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
            Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                markerSize = new_val.intValue();
                communalWeb();
            }

    });
```

How to make it only change my graph when mouse is released?

Comment: Can you use the `setOnMouseReleased()` method to set the action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OnMouseReleased`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication231 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {


        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 0);
        slider.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
            System.out.println(slider.getValue());
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane(slider);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`valueChanging` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#valueChangingProperty). The property is `true` when the user is dragging the thumb and `false` once they release it.

```
slider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if (!newVal) {
        double value = slider.getValue();
        // call your method
    }
});
```

If you need the previous value as well then you'd want to store it somewhere when the `valueChanging` property changes to `true`.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;

public class SliderTest {

    @FXML
    private Slider slider;
    private double oldSliderValue;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        slider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (newVal) {
                oldSliderValue = slider.getValue();
            } else {
                double newSliderValue = slider.getValue();
                if (oldSliderValue != newSliderValue) {
                    // call your method
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Since the `valueChanging` property is writable you can add your own logic that determines whether or not it is changing as well.

*Note: There is one issue, however. The property is not changed when the user clicks somewhere on the `Slider` to change its value (rather than dragging the thumb). A possible solution to this would be to also listen to the `value` property and only act if `isValueChanging()` returns `false`. This solution also has its issues though (clicking somewhere on the `Slider` **then** dragging doesn't set `valueChanging` to `true`).*

*Note #2: After messing around with this for a little bit I found this workaround for the issue mentioned above. As mentioned at the bottom of this answer, however, it is probably better to use the solution in [Sedrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51640273/6395627).*

*Combine this with listening to the `valueChanging` property.*

```
slider.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> slider.setValueChanging(true));
slider.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> slider.setValueChanging(false));
```

*This will change the property if you press-then-release anywhere on the `Slider` even if the `value` doesn't change.*

---

Another (probably better) option would be to use the [`onMouseReleased` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseReleasedProperty) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51640273/6395627)).

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code does this:

```
 slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
     slider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
     if(!slider.isValueChanging()){
         label.setText(String.format("%.0f",slider.getValue()));
        }
     });
```